# Magento - Subscription product - need to revert to another product after initial period

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, recurring

**Magento 1.9.0.1 with Recurring /Subscription module by anywebsol.**

We have a grouped product with three associated products within itself.

I is a monthly subscription (no issues).

II will be a fixed pay for first 3 months

III will be a fixed pay for first 6 months.

The Grouped product alone will be shown in the catalog. For II & III buyers/subscribers, after the initial period (of 3 or 6 months), **the subscription should automatically switchover to Monthly or Option I.**

Is this possible? Can the 3-month and 6-month product be altered using a cron job to convert to montly subscription after the end date? Configurable product? or is there better way to do this with your extension.

Would appreciate early responses. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the existing framework in Magento with the Trial period options set to 3 and 6 months with the same recurring profile as your monthly subscription which would start at the end of the trial period.

This wouldn't require any additional code to work.

More info here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/

Comment: Thanks for the info. We cannot use The recurring profile, because we need Authorize.net PG. We would be using one of the Recurring extensions (anywebsol or aheadworks) which support Authorize.net-CIM. Also, for accounting/reporting purposes, we need the customers to switch between Monthly-product to 3month-product? Thanks.